# How can I give the player the impression of speed?

Tags: graphic-effects, user-experience

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Effects to make a speeding spaceship look faster](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8535/effects-to-make-a-speeding-spaceship-look-faster)

I am currently developing a racing game akin to F-Zero in that the race is held at very fast speeds. The player is therefore placed in a 3rd person view.

Graphically, I'm thinking of using motion blur and lowering the camera angle when the ship is going faster to give the player the impression of speed. This from the fact that the closer you are to the ground, the more you percieve speed.

[This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8535/effects-to-make-a-speeding-spaceship-look-faster) has intersting answers, but don't really apply because the effect needs to be progressive and constant, not like a boost effect.

I was wondering if these techniques are viable, and if any other techniques exist?

Comment: I am voting to close. This question is a possible duplicate to the question you linked to. The answer in it works for your question as well.

Comment: While the questions are similar, I don't think they're duplicates.  Many of the suggestions there may be helpful but many more are more specific to showing a _change_ in speed, not just the feel of _constant_ high speed which is what it sounds like the OP is looking for.

Comment: I'm also voting to close. The effects are the same. If your vehicle is always at a very high speed, you might need to make the effects less strong so that don't get distracting when they last such a long time.

Comment: @bummzack I have asked for an admin to close then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the answers at the linked question may help.  Here are some other ideas off the top of my head.

Lots of what I remember about FZero was the ground and barrier textures that were very obviously striped/tiled in ways that they weren't very "long" in the "forward" direction.  As you pass by these elements, they seemed to whiz by at very high speed.  Very commonly, the ground textures would change to a different pattern, further enhancing that feel of speed.

Very responsive, almost jumpy/jittery, controls give a feel of speed as well.  In FZero, very slight shifts left and right are actually rather noticeable.

Speed lines (wind-like particles) may or may not work for your environment.  They're probably at least worth an iteration or two.

Banked turns.  Play off the knowledge players may have that banked turns are related to high-speed driving.

I like the idea of the lower camera angle. Staying tight(-ish) on the vehicle will certainly make the environment local to the camera pass by more quickly.  The closer the camera is to the vehicle will increase this effect but, of course, be wary of making the game unplayable through being unable to see enough.