# Special Effects in a 3d game

Tags: 3d, animation, opengl-es

I am creating a 3d game ( a car racing game) using opengl ES.
i know the rendering concept and also using a physics engine for all the physics stuff.
All modeling is done using 3d modeling softwares.

Now my question how to do the special effects within a game.

For example like when a car collides and toggle how to slow down all the environment effects which i saw in other available games.
OR
Nitrogen gas effects in a car race game.

Any suggestions will be of great help.
I guess my question is clear, if not feel free to ask anything.

Comment: Unfortunately your question isn't clear at all. What do you mean when you say animation? And then you talk about graphical effects and slowing down game-time? What exactly is it you're having trouble with?

Comment: Ok, i am confused between animation and graphical effects. but my main criterion is regarding graphical effects.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest editing your question a bit to make it clear that you're asking about graphical effects and not 3d animation, just to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to slow down all the environment effects

This is usually done by scaling down the time.  So 1 second in real time is like a 1/4 second in game time.  On top of this there are appropriate sound effects, etc.

> Nitrogen gas effects in a car race game

This is a completely different effect.  At its most basic level you can get by with just tightening the FOV and upping the motion blur.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
do you have any link or ebook regarding this..?OR can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: For the latter check out this question http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8535/effects-to-make-a-speeding-spaceship-look-faster